# Google Maps ignore region of placeholder container

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Example situation: my Google Maps map is in div#maps. div#maps has a half transparent menu layn over it on the top. That means the top 100px of div#maps is unclickable. However, when I for example use a function like "fit maps to marker bounds", the topmost marker will be underneath the overlying menu.

Is there a way to tell Google maps that the map should be rendered in the full div, but that the area that we're working in should be 100px off the top?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to offset the center of a Google maps (API v3) in pixels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473367/how-to-offset-the-center-of-a-google-maps-api-v3-in-pixels)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to offset the center point in Google maps api V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656743/how-to-offset-the-center-point-in-google-maps-api-v3)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26192440/1238965

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know what to search for, but that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Answer has been given before. I didn't know the right words for asking the question so I couldn't find an answer to it, but, as pointed out in comments, answers can be found here:

[How to offset the center of a Google maps (API v3) in pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473367/how-to-offset-the-center-of-a-google-maps-api-v3-in-pixels)

[How to offset the center point in Google maps api V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656743/how-to-offset-the-center-point-in-google-maps-api-v3)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26192440/1238965